# Value too large

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

There are 30 people who have to be seated into 5 rows of equal size where each row has 6 people and many people have preferences for which row they sit in. Other than that, people don’t really care which seat they get in a row. So I have to calculate the numbe of ways 30 people can be split into 5 rows of the same size and so far I have calculated this for each row and at the end I am getting a large value which is: $$\frac{30!}{(6!)^5}$$

Now, I am not sure if it's correct or not as the value is too big. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use big integer libraries. There's a ton of them. Here's one that I found, and I used for RSA encryption. https://github.com/sjhalayka/RSA/blob/master/rsa.cpp

Comment: This looks right

Comment: I don’t understand “Iam not sure if it's correct or not as the value is too big”. What means to big here? To big for what?

Comment: You check your reasoning with smaller numbers, say 2 rows of 2.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{30!}{(6!)^5}$$
$$=\frac{265252859812191058636308480000000}{720^5} $$
$$=\frac{265252859812191058636308480000000}{193491763200000}$$
$$=1370874167589326400$$

The computation is straightforward; you just need a programming environment that can store the exact value of $30!$ (which requires 108 bits or 33 decimal digits).

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. It is simply [the multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_to_multinomials); see
$$
\binom {30}{6, 6, 6, 6, 6} = \binom {30}{6} \binom {24}{6} \binom {18}{6} \binom {12}{6} \binom {6}{6} = \frac {30!}{{\left( 6! \right)}^{5}}.
$$